# Nested dictionary from a 2 column tsv file with counting repetitions

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So I have a tsv file with columns A and B. Both contain only strings. Strings in column A and B can repeat themselves. So this is something that I am trying to achieve: Info in column B would be the animal while info in column A would be the breed or type of that animal, and then I would like to count the repetitions.

```
{Animals: {"dog": {"Buldog": 23} {"Yorke":19} {"Wolf": 35} } {"fish": 
{"Salmon":10} {"Carp": 5} } }
```

Any tips would be highly appreciated!

The tsv file is not in english, so below I created something (please don't laugh) that retains the properties of what that tsv file has.

Yorkie Dog

Wolf   Dog

Salmon Fish

Yorkie Dog

Carp   Fish

Carp   Fish

Lion   Cat

Tiger  Cat

Yorkie Dog
.

.

.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your tsv file?

Comment: @AmeyDahale Would this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
occurence_dict = {"Animals":{}}
with open("path_to_your_file_tsv") as file_:
    for line in file_:
        line = line.split("\t")
        breed,animal=line[0],line[1]
        occurence_dict["Animals"].setdefault(animal,{})
        occurence_dict["Animals"][animal].setdefault(breed,0)
        occurence_dict["Animals"][animal][breed]+=1
```

It should works:)